# Oracle insert character into a string

Tags: oracle

I have this table of rows

```
RowA
______
ABC123
DEF432
WER677
JKL342
```

how can I add a '_' in between the record using oracle to this? 
Assuming to add on the last 4 character.

```
RowA
______
ABC_123
DEF_432
WER_677
JKL_342
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would try something like:

```
Update Table_name set table_column = substr(table_column, 1, 3) || '_' || substr(table_column, 4);
```

The `SUBSTR` functions allows you to extract a substring from a string.
The syntax for the `SUBSTR` function is:

```
SUBSTR( string, start_position, [ length ] )
```

`string` is the source string.

`start_position` is the position for extraction. The first position in the string is always 1.

`length` is optional. It is the number of characters to extract. If this parameter is omitted, the SUBSTR function will return the entire string.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach, using [regexp_replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions149.htm#i1305521) regular expression function:

```
 select regexp_replace(RowA, '^([[:alpha:]]{3})', '\1_') as res
   from your_table
```

Result:

```
RES
----------
ABC_123
DEF_432
WER_677
JKL_342
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/858a6/1)