# Insert character between string Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to insert character string after each character in Oracle SQL.

Example:

```
ABC  will A,B,C

DEFG will be D,E,F,G
```

This question gives only one character in string

[Oracle insert character into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230658/oracle-insert-character-into-a-string)

Answer (score 5):

Edit: As some fellows have mentioned, Oracle does not admit this regex. So my approach would be to do a regex to match all characters, add them a comma after the character and then removing the last comma.

```
WITH regex AS (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC', '(.)', '\1,') as reg FROM dual) SELECT SUBSTR(reg, 1, length(reg)-1) FROM regex;
```

Note that with the solution of `rtrim` there could be errors if the string you want to parse has a final ending comma and you don't want to remove it.

Previous solution: (Not working on Oracle)

Check if this does the trick:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC', '(.)(?!$)', '\1,') FROM dual;
```

It does a `regexp_replace` of every character, but the last one for the same character followed by a ,

To see how `regexp_replace` works I recommend you: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

Comment: Lookahead and Lookbehind are not supported in Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

SELECT rtrim(REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC', '(.)', '\1,'),',') "REGEXP_REPLACE"  FROM dual;

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using:

- **REGEXP_REPLACE**
- **RTRIM**

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'ABC' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'DEFG' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'XYZ' str FROM dual
  5  )
  6  -- end of sample_data mimicking a real table
  7  SELECT str,
  8    rtrim(regexp_replace(str, '(\w?)', '\1,'),',') new_str
  9  FROM sample_data;

STR  NEW_STR
---- ----------
ABC  A,B,C
DEFG D,E,F,G
XYZ  X,Y,Z
```

Comment: Why do we need `(1)?` in  regex pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no way to negate the end of string in an Oracle regex (that does not support lookarounds), you may use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC', '([^,])([^,])','\1,\2'),
    '([^,])([^,])',
    '\1,\2')
    AS Result from dual
```

See the [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=561844bd5911bb0f457ebd209c7e42b0). The point here is to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` with `([^,])([^,])` pattern *twice* to cater for consecutive matches.

The `([^,])([^,])` pattern matches any non-comma char into Group 1 (`\1`) and then any non-comma char into Group 2 (`\2`), and inserts a comma in between them.